# Not able to select Group AND or Group OR while creating a view in crm 2011

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

[image: Screen shot of error while creating view]

I'm trying to create a view for an entity but i'm not able to give condition or use group AND or group OR.

screen shot above shows the error i'm  getting. How to overcome this.

I went to customization - `entity` -> `view` -> `New`.

When i clicked on Edit Filter Criteria The window is showing only 'clear' 'Group AND' and 'Group OR'.

When i clicked on group and its giving this alert.You can see all three popup windows in screen shot.

Comment: "i'm not able to give condition or use group AND or group OR" -- can you be more specific? in your screenshot that second window has no conditions in it, and the message says select conditions before grouping... add a condition first -- how are you trying to add a condition and what is stopping you?

Comment: You noticed correctly BenPatterson, the second window is not showing any conditions. That is the actual problem. I don't know why i'm not able to see conditions. I'm able to give conditions in all other entities but its not visible only in this entity

Comment: Sorry James Wood for late reply. This is a custom entity called rob. I couldn't find the reason or solution for this problem so 'm creating new entity.

Comment: Be interested to see if this works on the new entity. Sounds like an odd problem, can any other users do it? Might be permissions, or possibly some odd browser issue

Answer (score 1):

To use the Group AND/OR feature, you first must create the conditions you'd like to group.

Then select the arrow button on the left and choose "Select Row" for each of the items you'd like to group.

Then click the "Group OR" or "Group AND" button

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply James , but i'm not able to create conditions. As you can see from screen shot above, window is showing only three buttons('clear','group and','group or') but no options to create a condition. (check out middle window in screen shot).

Comment: @Maddy Is the view customizable?  From the view listing screen [Customizations > Entities > (your entity) > Views], select your view, then "More Actions" > "Managed Properties".  Make sure Customizable is set to True.

Comment: @james-wood Thanks for adding the screenshot

Comment: Paul Way thank you for your reply, i checked in customisations. The property is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Read your comments, I understand the problem now. Which entity is this?

To create a condition please follow these steps.

[image]

Comment: James Wood, i'm not able to see that 'Select' option only. I couldn't find any answer so i'm creating a new entity with all fields. Thank you everyone for your precious time and reply.